# Read an xml file in my Android app

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a file (xml) that I need to read in my android app. I dont know how can I access the values for e.g. SN$ I need the value 1111, PNAME$ value user1 and so on. Please can anyone help me with this issue. Thank you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://...">
SN$1111
PNAME$user1
PCODE$63 
</string>
```

Comment: Is that the whole file?

Comment: Yes that the whole file.

Comment: Then just open the file and read from input stream line by line. Check every line for the dollar character. If it has the dollar character use String.split to split on that character.

Comment: Can you suggest any link that can help me or can you help me with code ?

Comment: You are encouraged to search this site for code.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply read the file linewise and starting from the third line apply [string.split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) using "$" as delimiter. Then get the value from the array this function returns.

I assume, that all your xml files look like your sample.

Alternatively have a look at [DocumentBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html).